# WPF - Different Information displayed in a button. Possible with button control or is a CustomControl necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i need to build with WPF an button on which several information are provided. I made the here attached [Button Examle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlL4K.png) with paint. What the button needs to have:

- A border (thick on the top, thin on right, left and bottom) that can change its color
- A Text inside the thick top part of the border
- A icon and a dynamic text-field in the middle of the button (in the text only 2 digits of numbers are displayed)
- Change the backcolor of the button
- A section on the right of the button, that can change its color separatly from the button itself and display an additional icon

So far i tried to work with the standard wpf button but i didnt have success. I was able to creat the border with the different sizes but i cant place a text inside. Also i wasnt able to get all the elements inside the button with a StackPanel. I think that probably the standard button cant fulfill my requests so i maybe have to build my own button?

I hope you might have some ideas or hints for me if its possible with the standard control or if i better try to build a CustomControl.

Thanks and regards,
Mathias

Comment: everything you described can be achieved by changing Template of Button. Or if you need many new properties, create a custom button class, derived from Button - not CustomControl

Comment: From Review: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1):

I belive you could use Datatemplates for your cause, check this XAML:

```
<Button Margin="50,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="10,30,10,10" BorderBrush="Gray">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Button Name" Margin="0,-30,0,0" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray">
                                <Border Margin="5,20" BorderThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Icon" FontSize="24" Padding="5,10" Background="White"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                                <Border Margin="5,20" BorderThickness="5" UseLayoutRounding="False" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Text" FontSize="24" Padding="5,10" Background="White"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Background="DarkOrange">
                                <Border Margin="10,29" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Icon" FontSize="16" Background="White" Padding="1,5" Foreground="DarkOrange"></TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```